# AngularJS - Bind click event to children of directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm back to using AngularJS and I've forgotten everything. I have an div in my html view that contains a custom directive and the children DIVs have a `ng-repeat` directive, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="row" data-custom-directive>
<div class="col-xs-2 main-nav-cell" data-ng-repeat="nav in mainNavigation.topNavi" data-url="{{ nav.link }}">
    <div> {{ nav.name }} </div>
    <div class="item-counter" data-ng-show="nav.value > 0"> {{ nav.value }} </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now in my custom directive I wait for the `ng-repeat` to complete then I loop through the children DIVs and perform certain tasks (some I have omitted here).

```
.directive('customDirective', function ($location, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    'use strict';
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            $timeout(function () {

                var i,
                    list = angular.element(element),
                    cssCheck = function () {


                        for (i = 0; i < list[0].children.length; i++) {

                            /* 

                            Here I wish to set a click event on the Child DIV 
                            I have tried list.children()[i].click = fn & list.children()[i].bind('click' fn)
                            but nothing works!
                            */

                            // if the class is there remove it...
                            if (list.children()[i].classList.contains('is-active')) {
                                list.children()[i].classList.remove('is-active');
                            }


                            // if there is a match add the class...
                            if ($location.url().indexOf(list[0].children[i].getAttribute('data-url')) > 0) {
                                console.log('match');
                                list.children()[i].classList.add('is-active');
                            }

                        }

                    };

                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
                    cssCheck();
                });

                // original kickoff
                cssCheck();
            });
        }
    };
```

I want to assign a click event to the first child div (where I check the CSS) and perform certain tasks depending on the 'data-url' I don't really want to add a `ng-click` directive to the child in my HTML. Can someone please advise me on how to add a click event to the child div?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If Using jQuery:**

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        element.on('click', ':first', function () {
            console.log('inside event handler of the first child)
        })
    })
}
```

**If not using jQuery**

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        angular.element(element).on('click', function (evt) {
            var isFirstChild = (evt.target.parentElement.children[0] === evt.target);

            if (isFirstChild) {
                // do the stuff
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using jQuery, I thought maybe I could use $on ?